# How to convert from String to Enum dynamically?

Tags: java, enums

I'm trying to build a dynamic wrapper that uses reflection to access properties of objects. My approach works with different kinds of objects – but I still have an issue with Enums.

Let's assume I already have the proper setter und getter and I want to invoke them in different situations. For example I'm trying to save a given value via the following code:

```
public void save() {
    try {
        // Enums come in as Strings... we need to convert them!
        if (this.value instanceof String && this.getter.getReturnType().isEnum()) {

            // FIXME: HOW?

        }
        this.setter.invoke(this.entity, this.value);
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Die Eigenschaft " + this.property + " von Entity " + this.entity.getClass().getSimpleName() + " konnte nicht geschrieben werden!", ex);
    }
}
```

**How can I convert the String object to the proper Enum value?**

I know about `MyEnum.valueOf(String)`... but what if I can't name the Enum in my source code? I've not managed to use something like

```
this.value = Enum.valueOf(this.getter.getReturnType(), this.value);
```

Comment: Well, I guess you can use `.getDeclaredFields()` from the class object...

Comment: I know the field... even getter and setter. I don't manage to convert to the proper Enum element at the moment.

Comment: what is the problem with saying this.value = YourEnum.valueOf(theString)?

Comment: You can't reference an `Enum` with `this` as they are implicitly static.

Comment: @DegenSharew I don't know YourEnum... it may be any of MyEnum1, MyEnum2, ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a Enum class and a string value you can convert to the Enum object corresponding to the string via the following static method defined in `java.lang.Enum`:

```
static <T extends Enum<T>> T valueOf(Class<T> enumType, String name)
```

e.g.

```
java.awt.Window.Type type = Enum.valueOf(java.awt.Window.Type.class, "NORMAL");
```

Note that `Enum.valueOf`throws an `IllegalArgumentException` if there is no corresponding enum constant.

You can't invoke `Enum.valueOf` without a cast from your method, since `getter.getReturnType()` is a `Class<?>`.

So a helper function might handle the cast:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static <E extends Enum<E>> E getEnumValue(Class<?> c, String value)
{
     return Enum.valueOf((Class<E>)c, value);
}
```

and you just use it in your code:

```
if (this.value instanceof String && this.getter.getReturnType().isEnum())
     this.value = getEnumValue(getter.getReturnType(), (String)this.value));
```

Note that any solution which loops over `Enum.getEnumConstants()` will create a temporary array for the constants, whereas `Enum.valueOf` uses an internal cache.

Comment: This helper function is a good point... the exakt syntax blocked my attempts so far. Thanks... I'll give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

Just found one way... but it seems "dirty"... any better?

```
if (this.value instanceof String && this.getter.getReturnType().isEnum()) {
    for (Object v : this.getter.getReturnType().getEnumConstants()) {
        if (v.toString().equals(this.value)) {
            this.value = v;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how does this work then? getEnumConstants is only valid if the class is of type ENUM.

Comment: No, it is not... http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants()

Comment: The method simply returns an empty list if it is not applicable. But I can call it on any class. It compiles...